# Precision of integers vs. Precision of floating numbers

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

It seems that Mathematica can handle very big integers accurately, but cannot do the same for floating numbers.

See the following code:

```
aa = 10^200;
aa = aa + 1; 
N[aa*Sqrt[2] - Round[aa*Sqrt[2]], 20]
```

The error message is

N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating -141421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799073247846210703885038753432764157273501384623091229702492483605585073721264412149709993583141322266592750559275579995050115278206057148+1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000<<36>>00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 <<1>>.

**How to handle this kind of problem?**

Comment: This usually happens when the result of subtracting two numbers results in something that is relatively very tiny compared to the original numbers. Consider it a warning that subtractive cancellation is happening. Anyway: `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 250}, N[aa*Sqrt[2] - Round[aa*Sqrt[2]], 20]]`.

Comment: You mean it is just a warning message, not an error message?

Comment: Yes, it's a warning, but a very important one. It says that the result may be rubbish. In fact, in this specific case it *is* rubbish.  There is not a very clear distinction between "error" and "warning" messages in Mathematica.  The practical question is: can you ignore it?  You definitely should not.

Comment: You should look up [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).  When such things happen, most systems just give you a wrong result, without any warning. Mathematica goes further in helping you and warns you that the result may be rubbish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oftentimes, to get a result with `k` digits of precision, the arithmetic needs to be done with more than `k` digits.  Mathematica automatically increases the number of digits it uses to get a result with the requested precision.  But there is a limit on how much it will increase it: `$MaxExtraPrecision`.

Why is there a limit?  Consider examples like

```
N[
 Sin[Pi/9] - Root[-3 + 36 #1^2 - 96 #1^4 + 64 #1^6 &, 4],
 10
 ]
```

This triggers the same error.  But no matter how much you increase the max extra precision, the error won't go away, because the *exact* result happens to be 0 here.  Proving that it is zero is not trivial though, and Mathematica does not realize that it is so.

---

The solution, as J.M. said, is to allow for a higher precision increase during computations:

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 250}, 
 N[aa*Sqrt[2] - Round[aa*Sqrt[2]], 20]]
```